# FormatterLineAggregator in spring

Tags: spring

I am using  FormatterLineAggregator. For eg:

```
<beans:property name="lineAggregator">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
        <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
             <beans:property name="names" value="desc1, desc2, desc3, desc4, desc5" /> 
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>

        <beans:property name="format" value="%-4s%-9s%-30s%-30s%-30s" /> 
    </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

The desc2 is of size 9. But I am getting a value of size 4 from database. So in the output file, spaces appear for the remaining 5 characters. I want to remove this space.Even if the size is 9 spaces should not follow desc1.